# mongoClient.connect VS mongoose.connect in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm a beginner in backend.I have a doubt about MongoDB.
What are the differences between **mongoClient.connect** and **mongoose.connect** in express framework?

Comment: Good question!  Indeed, at the beginning, It can confusing! I would suggest to use mongoose.

Comment: @JorgePires : But if you're completely new & with no support + has to build something real quick then learning mongoose can take a while *(Vs)* native driver is easy to work on, I agree with you - when your application grows overtime then mongoose can help you a lot (but it all depends on how big is ur app & ur needs) :-)

Comment: indeed, building schema can be challenging!

Comment: Please, add what you said to your answer!

Comment: @JorgePires : Yeah sometimes building a toy with too many options can lead you to confusion, let it be in comments I don't want someone to discourage using mongoose by pointing it out in answer, they might not feel comfortable using it  though they've time to learn - let users do r&d and find the best for them, some might feel its easy on first go, never know :-)

Comment: I myself have found easier first!

Answer (score 5):

These two can be different :

Usually when you use `mongoClient.connect`, then you should probably be using [node-mongodb-native-driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/)

**Sample Code :**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect(url)
```

But when you see `mongoose.connect` then [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com) is being used in that project :

**Sample Code :**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect(url)
```

These two are different packages through which you can connect to MongoDB using node.js. If you use `mongoose` then probably you might not need nodejs-mongodb native driver as mongoose has a lot of functions which are basically wrappers to existing native driver. Internally mongoose would use native driver. If you wanted to make your MongoDB look schema based then mongoose can help you a lot as you'll define schema for your collection & operate on those schemas while data insertion.